# How do I make an android webview to scale and fit the page to the app?

Tags: android, webview, scale, viewport

I'm making an android app which suppose to act like a browser for my website. Simply a website app.
But for some reason I can't make the application fit and scale the page to the app.
I've searched and tried and nothing worked.

Here is a part of my code:

```
private final String URL = "http://justplaymobile.com/html5games/smedia/tiptap/";
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final Activity activity = this;
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    final WebView webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview1);
    webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    webview.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webview.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(true);
    webview.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);

    WebSettings settings = webview.getSettings();
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    settings.setSupportZoom(true);
    settings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    settings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    settings.setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.NARROW_COLUMNS);

    webview.loadUrl(URL);

    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return false;
        }
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon){
            // I've tried to put stuff here which haven't helped
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url){
            // I've tried to put stuff here which haven't helped
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        }
    });
}
```

When I enter the same website via the browser, it looks great and fits itself to the window with the viewport meta tag, but it doesn't works in the webview.
All I managed to do is fit the page to the webview's width. I also need it to fit to the height. Just like overview mode suppose to be (it doesn't really works).
I also tried various combinations of setInitialScale which wasn't so helpful either.
I'm not looking for a solution that includes scaling/zooming via javascript.

- I'm using SDKv10.
- While testing, the simulator sometimes managed to fit the page into the webview, but when testing on a real device (tried on several phones and tablets) it didn't.

Thank you!

Comment: use this   webview.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN); reply if this doesnt work for you, or even if it does!

Comment: try to set supportZoom to false?

Comment: both didn't work. any other ideas? thanks